# VGA video switching using TS5v522

Tags: switching, vga

I am trying to bring video card signal to switch to  a single monitor. I was hoping to use the TS5v522c but am not having much success. Data sheet below.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5v522c.pdf#page=5
Has anyone done this and is there a circuit lay out I can use that is proved working.

I have taken VGA from a PC video card, supply at +5v, To test the chip I am bringing one colour and passing it through but am not getting any output.Red in on pin 2(AR)
Red out on pin 3 (1R). Unused i/p and o/p are floating.
Pullup resistors are on OE and pull down on SEL lines. The other colours and H+V syncs  are wired direct to the monitor.

I unfortunately do not have access to an oscilloscope or schematic layout software.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, we can't just recommend a working "circuit lay out" because recommendations are off-topic -- we can only try to help you figure out what's wrong with your design. We're going to need more information to help diagnose the problem -- schematics of your circuit at a minimum, measured quantities like voltage, etc. Also, I wouldn't leave inputs floating even if they are unused.

Comment: What logical tests have you performed to verify your design follows the datasheet? Are there any deviations?  Validate all input assumption